# T-SQL case error: expressions may only be nested to level 10

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following code with a none-nested case statement (as can be seen, there's only one case statement) with 13 arguments, yet I get an error saying

> "Case expressions may only be nested to level 10".

It does work when I use less arguments, but that doesn't really help me because I need all arguments for my required result set.

```
select        ID,
              CASE 
              when  sum(Y) between 0 and 30 then 1
              when  sum(Y) between 31 and 70 then 2
              when  sum(Y) between 71 and 100 then 3
              when  sum(Y) between 101 and 200 then 4
              when  sum(Y) between 201 and 300 then 5
              when  sum(Y) between 301 and 400 then 6
              when  sum(Y) between 401 and 500 then 7
              when  sum(Y) between 501 and 600 then 8
              when  sum(Y) between 601 and 700 then 9
              when  sum(Y) between 701 and 800 then 10
              when  sum(Y) between 801 and 900 then 11
              when  sum(Y) between 901 and 1000 then 12
              when  sum(Y) > 1000 then 13 
              end 
from X
group by ID
;
```

I did manage to solve the issue with splitting my case argument over two different select statements and using UNION between them to get my required result set, but it feels as if I could've done a better job at it, as the original case argument is not n
ested

Comment: Are you [sending this to a linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42850/3690)? I can't repro this as written. This shows no error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a76abe662b7a2a0fe4ff46f9b0782bca

Comment: You could workaround it by collapsing `between 101 and 1000` to a single case branch and calculating the result with some maths

Comment: At this point, it would seem to be a better idea to join your current result set to a table (expression) that contains the necessary ranges and the final values, rather than enumerating each range in a `WHEN` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know. That was already hyperlinked in my original comment

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Oops, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to join it to a `VALUES` table constructor (a virtual table).

Because the value is an aggregate, it may be easier to do this in a correlated subquery, rather than putting the whole thing into a CTE:

```sql
select
    ID,
    (
        SELECT v.val
        FROM (VALUES
              (0,   30,  1),
              (31,  70,  2),
              (71,  100, 3),
              (101, 200, 4),
              (201, 300, 5),
              (301, 400, 6),
              (401, 500, 7),
              (501, 600, 8),
              (601, 700, 9),
              (701, 800, 10),
              (801, 900, 11),
              (901, 1000, 12),
              (1001, 2147483647, 13)
        ) v(nStart, nEnd, val)
        WHERE SUM(y) BETWEEN v.nStart AND v.nEnd
    )
from X
group by ID;
```

Comment: Sadly I can't create a new table due to other tools outside of my DB relating to this query

Comment: Erm, it's not a new table, it's a *virtual* table constructor only visible to this query

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with linked servers.  One method in your case is to use arithmetic to simplify the logic:

```
select ID,
       (case when sum(Y) between 0 and 30 then 1
             when sum(Y) between 31 and 70 then 2
             when sum(Y) between 71 and 100 then 3
             when sum(Y) > 1000 then 13
             else ceiling(sum(Y) / 100.0) + 2
        end) 
from X
group by ID
```